# Recursive program in RISC-V (procedure call)

Tags: recursion, riscv

I'm trying to implement the recursive equation here, but I have no idea what's going wrong with my code.
It keeps output 1 no matter what input I gave.
The function is as follows:
T(n) = T(n-100) + 2*T(n/2) + 5  if n > 1
= 1                        otherwise

```
.globl __start

.text

__start:
    # read from standard input a0 = n
    addi a0, zero, 5
    ecall
    
################################################################################
#                        Recursive function                                    #
#                  T(n) = T(n-100)+2*T((n/2))+5 if n>1                         #
#                       = 1                     otherwise                      #
################################################################################
    addi s2,x0,1   #for base case
    addi s3,x0,2   #for comparison
    blt a0,s3,result

recur:
    addi a2,a2,5
    addi a3,a3,9
    addi sp,sp,-8    #store 2 registers into stack
    sw x1,4(sp)
    sw a0,0(sp)
    bge a0,s3,L1
    bge a0,s3,L2
    addi s2,x0,1
    addi sp,sp,8
    jal x0,result

L1:                #to do T(n-100)
    addi a0,a0,-100
    jal x1,recur
    addi x6,x10,0        #T(n-100) stored in x6
    lw x10,0(sp)
    lw x1,4(sp)
    addi sp,sp,8
    jalr x0,0(x1)
    
L2:                #to do T(n/2)
    div a0,a0,s3
    jal x1,recur
    addi x7,x10,0        #T(n/2) stored in x7
    lw a0,0(sp)
    lw x1,4(sp)
    addi sp,sp,8
    mul x7,x7,s3
    add s2,x6,x7
    addi s2,s2,5
    jalr x0,0(x1)

################################################################################
result:
    # prints the result in s2
    addi a0, zero, 1
    addi a1, s2, 0
    ecall
    
    # ends the program with status code 0
    addi a0, zero, 10
    ecall
```

Comment: Step through the code to see what happens: At L1 and L2, you `jal x1, recur` expecting `recur` to return, but `recur` never returns. If it hits the base case, it just prints `s2` and exits.

Comment: You both call `recur` as a function as well as "fall" into it from `main`.  This is inconsistent.  When you fall into it from `main` there exists no caller to return to, there's no return address of where to go back, but when it is called (albeit recursively) it must return to its caller using the provided return address.  The way to fix it is to also call it from `main` so that it is only ever called with a proper return address.  Try to clearly separate the `main` code from function code.

Comment: It is confusing that you refer to register 10 by two different names (`x10` and `a0`).